# does operator () parenthesis get called on object created within a function call?

Tags: c++

I have a class that acts like a "smart pointer" for handles.

```
#define DEST 123

HANDLE OpenHandle(int dest);
class SmartHandle;
void SendMsg(HANDLE dest_handle);

SendMsg(SmartHandle(OpenHandle(DEST)))
```

This construct is used often in my code so it does work but I don't understand why.

`OpenHandle(DEST)` returns a handle to the "smart pointer" class

`SendMsg` - takes an argument of the same type that is return by `OpenHandle` which is a simple `HANDLE` aka `void*`

For this thing to work, and it does, it must mean that `HANDLE SmartHandle::operator()` is invoked.

**QUESTION**

Why does `HANDLE SmartHandle::operator()` get invoked?

Looking at the code, I would just say that an object of type `SmartHandle` is created and nothing is returned and then `SmartHandle` destructor is called.

Comment: not everything that looks like `operator()` is actually `operator()`, that would be just too easy :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a call such as:

```
HANDLE h;
SmartHandle(h);
```

Does not call `SmartHandle::operator()`. Instead, it creates a temporary object of type `SmartHandle`, constructed with the `h` argument. That is, it is calling the constructor `SmartHandle::SmartHandle(HANDLE)`.

Your code works because you class most likely has a `operator HANDLE()` to convert an object of your type back into a `HANDLE`. So you code does this sequence of operations:

```
{
  HANDLE tmp1 = OpenHandle(DEST);
  SmartHandle tmp2(tmp1);
  HANDLE tmp3 = tmp2.operator HANDLE();
  SendMsg(tmp3);
}     //at the end of the full sentence temporaries are destroyed.
```

Comment: yes you are correct it does have `operator HANDLE()` but how and why is that function called?

Comment: Also is `HANDLE operator()` different from `operator HANDLE()` ?

Comment: It's called because your ``SendMsg`` method expects a ``HANDLE`` but it gets a ``SmartHandle``. There are two options how this can work: ``SmartHandle`` has an ``operator HANDLE()`` to convert it to ``HANDLE`` or ``HANDLE`` has a conversion constructor taking a ``SmartHandle``. Since the first one is true the operator is called. Otherwise it would be a compile error because of type differences.

Comment: And ``operator HANDLE()`` is the conversion operator from your ``SmartHandle`` to ``HANDLE``. Whereas ``HANDLE operator()`` is the functor operator, which can be used in a ``SmartHandle`` that will return a ``HANDLE``. ``SmartHandle s; HANDLE h1 = s; // calls operator HANDLE(). HANDLE h2 = s2(); // calls HANDLE operator()``. You could also add additional parameters to this operator, so ``SmartHandle`` can be used like a function.